# Exporting a method in a class in ES2015

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm trying to export the toString method alone but it's failing. The first export is working fine but the other one I added is failing.

```
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  toString() {
    return `(${this.x}, ${this.y}`;
  }
}

export {Point as XPoint}; // this is working great
```

but this is failing

```
export {Point.prototype.toString as PointToString};
```

What is the proper export syntax for exporting specific method in a class?

Here is the error that webpack is saying:

ERROR in ./es6/Point.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/demouser/repos/webpack-es6-demo/es6/Point.js: Unexpected token (12:13)

Comment: sorry, I didn't include the error. I'll edit my post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use identifiers inside of export specifiers:

```
const PointToString = Point.prototype.toString;
export { PointToString }
```

See: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-exports

Comment: Thank you so much vkurchatkin!